# codeigniter select statement not returning anything

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get some records matching username and password from the database. I used the following code:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $username ,
    'password' => $password
);    
//show_error('Password: ' . $password . "    Username: " . $username);
/*Query database for details matching username & password*/
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$result = $this->db->get();
$queryResult;
//show_error('ResultSet Rows: ' . $result->num_rows());
if($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $queryResult = $result->result_array();
}else{
    $queryResult = "Error retrieving data from table";
}

return $queryResult;
```

When the num_rows() function outputs, it shows 0. This can only mean that nothing is being selected. Is something wrong with the query?

Regards,

P.S. I am using show_error() function to track variables values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing use this

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $username ,
    'password' => $password
);    


$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$result = $this->db->get()->row();

echo '<pre>';
print_R($result);
```

And for more use `$this->db->last_query()`
which will output the last query run which you can copy and test in phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks your code helped in understanding the reason more.I way using the encrypt->encode() codeigniter function to encrypt my password. When i removed password from where() it worked. it means that function doesn't generate same output always.

Comment: You are welcome. I was surprised that how select isn't working cos no one has ever complained about it. Glad you found a solution!